# datatables sorting css issue

Tags: css, datatables

I am using the following guide to change the sorting icons
https://datatables.net/blog/2014-06-06

I am using the datatables css file for this integration:
https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/integration/font-awesome/dataTables.fontAwesome.css

However, once applied there is an odd behaviour with one of the old arrows still appearing?

screenshot of issue here (highlighted in red):

[image]

Appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Please post your code or setup a fiddle.

Comment: here you go.. i have highlighted the problem area: https://postimg.org/image/pm93yosrj/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Posting code as images on a programming Q&A site is ....Would you post a textual description of your photos on a photo showoff site? :)